# Display click count in JavaScript before the count

Tags: javascript, onclick, click-counting

I have a simple script designed to increment a counter each time an image is clicked:

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
```

The html:

```
<img id="heart" src="../assets/images/redheart.png" title="Give Love!" onclick="clickCounter()"><p id="counter"></p>
```

It's working fine but I'd like to be able to display the count BEFORE the click. Right now the counter shows only once the image button is clicked.

Thanks for any and all input.

Comment: So make a method that outputs it and call it on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't what you're going for, please let me know.

**First, a few tweaks:**

- For accessibility reasons:

  - I made the `<img>` a `<button>` (with a background image). Buttons are super accessible and keyboard friendly (tab, enter key, etc.)
  - Added an `aria-label` to the button, since it contains no text content
- Cleaned up the JavaScript a little.

**Behavior:**

On first page load…

[image]

Then we perform five clicks followed by a page refresh.

[image]

**Note:** This demo will not work here on Stack Overflow due to security restrictions in the editor. Have a look over in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgejhcnf/3/) I've created.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", clickCounter);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showValue);

let counter = document.getElementById("counter");

function showValue() {
  counter.innerHTML = `Current count = ${localStorage.clickcount || 0}`;
}

function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    showValue();
  } else {
    counter.innerHTML = "Your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/benzlee/free-christmas/512/heart-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 64px 64px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button title="Give Love!" aria-label="Give Love!">
<div id="counter"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mgejhcnf/3/

Comment: that's is exactly what I was looking for:) Although I can't seem to get it to work. I'm used the "img" id instead of "button" like you have. Maybe I'm overlooking something. I'll keep trying and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @dreamerdan Maybe recreate your full demo on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) and I can help you there.

Comment: @dreamerdan Put the `JavaScript` at the bottom of your page, before the closing `</body>` tag, and surround it within `<script></script>`.

Comment: I got it to work. I will integrate it into my pages. I may need to add some additional code having to do with sessions that would allow a user to only like it once. I'm fairly new at this but a quick learner. I'm putting together a dating site and if you are available let me know. I could use your service:) Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @dreamerdan I'm available for full-stack contract work. Please contact me [here](https://andyhoffman.codes/#contact).

Comment: I will. thanks. Quick question though. Is there another way to call the querySelector if the html element is on a different page? I tested your code with everything on the same page and it works. But having a bit of an issue calling the element from another page.

Comment: @dreamerdan Seems you would need to do a bit of screen scraping to accomplish it. Probably warrants its own question.